# Could someone help me Understand ex23 in Zed Shaw's Learn Python 3 the Hard way

Tags: python

I'm trying to decipher Zed's ex23 and his explanation is somewhat helpful but I'm getting lost. This script deals with him trying to teach you how to decode and encode letters in different languages it seems. A few of these topics seem premature/ he didn't go over it yet, and he mentions that this is on the harder end than anything I've seen but I'm getting consistently lost. I'll try and explain what I can based on what I see, but I am unsure if I understand everything here.

```
import sys script, input_encoding, error = sys.argv
```

This is simple, we are just importing sys and defining argv's variables.

```
def main(language_file, encoding, errors):
    line = language_file.readline()
```

Defining the function titled main with three variables . Define line to read the line off the language file. How is language_file being defined? I don't see a definition anywhere?

```
if line:
    print_line(line, encoding, errors)  
    return main(language_file, encoding, errors)
```

The if line has something from what it is defined to be it will run the below. If it does not (AKA if it's false), then it won't. How can I get away with creating an if statement without defining the function in it above? Is there something I'm missing. Zed defined print_line below but uses it above? What does return main do? Does it mean that we return back to the base function?

```
def print_line(line, encoding, errors):
    next_lang = line.strip()  
    raw_bytes = next_lang.encode(encoding,
                                 errors=errors)
```

We are defining print_line here. What does the strip function do? What does errors=errors mean?

```
 cooked_string = raw_bytes.decode(encoding, errors=errors)
```

cooked_string we are defining as taking the raw bytes and encoding it...I think?

```
    print(raw_bytes, "<==>", cooked_string)


languages = open("languages.txt", encoding = "utf - 8")
```

Why is it languages vs language_file?

```
main(languages, input_encoding, error)
```

I think this exercise is a bit premature in this book or I'm just not seeing something. Any help to dissect this would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the full scrip uninterrupted without my comments:

```
def main(language_file, encoding, errors):
    line = language_file.readline() #defining line as a read off of language_file


    if line: # if line has something from what it is defined to be it will run the below. If it does not (AKA if it's false), then it won't.
        print_line(line, encoding, errors)  
        return main(language_file, encoding, errors)

def print_line(line, encoding, errors):
    next_lang = line.strip()  # what is strip?
    raw_bytes = next_lang.encode(encoding, errors=errors) 
    cooked_string = raw_bytes.decode(encoding, errors=errors) 

    print(raw_bytes, "<==>", cooked_string)


languages = open("languages.txt", encoding = "utf - 8")

main(languages, input_encoding, error)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer your questions in order:

1. How is language_file being defined? `language_file` is defined as a parameter to the main function. It is passed in when main is called below. It is a file that is opened in the `languages = open("languages.txt", encoding = "utf - 8")` line.
2. How can I get away with creating an if statement without defining the function in it above? This is tricky... Python is an interpreted language, meaning that it reads the code, runs the code and interperpates the python code to machine code at runtime. Because the `printline` function is defined above the call to the `main` function, it will work just fine. Think about where the functions are defined compared to where they are run.
3. The `return main(language_file, encoding, errors)` line calls the main function recursively. This means it will read the next line off of the file, until there is no more lines, then it will stop executing.
4. The strip function removes white space from the beginning and end of a string.
5. The `errors=errors` in the function definition sets a default parameter. It's saying when you only pass one parameter instead of two, set errors = errors. Errors is defined above in the import statement. See a geeks for geeks tutorial about different ways to deal with parameters to python functions [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/default-arguments-in-python/)
6. The two lines:

```
raw_bytes = next_lang.encode(encoding, errors=errors) 
cooked_string = raw_bytes.decode(encoding, errors=errors)
```

The first line creates a string of a byte representation of the string `next_lang` using the encoding specified. The second line decodes it to a python string. See [here](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/) for a table of utf-8 encodings for strings. utf-8 is just one encoding option. There are many different ways to encode a string into bytes.

6. Why is it languages vs language_file? languages is the variable that stores the file handle after opening it. Then language is passed as a paremeter to the main function. The main function's first parameter is named "language_file", so it is essentially renaming language to be language_file for the duration of the main function.